Is the joint distribution of integrated OU process a multivariate normal distribution?
Suppose $U_t$ is an OU process on $t\in[0,T]$, i.e.,
$$
\mathrm{d}U_t = -\kappa U_t \mathrm{d} t + \sigma \mathrm{d} B_t, \quad t\in[0,T], 
$$
where $U_0 \sim \pi$ which is the stationary distribution of $U_t$. We divide the time interval $[0,T]$ into $n$ small pieces with $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=T$ (where $t_i-t_{i-1}=\Delta t$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$).
What is the joint distribution of
$$
\left(\int_{t_0}^{t_1}U_s\mathrm{d}s,~\int_{t_1}^{t_2}U_s\mathrm{d}s,~\ldots, ~\int_{t_{n-1}}^{t_n}U_s\mathrm{d}s\right) ?
$$
Intuitively, I believe that the joint distribution is a multivariate normal distribution. Could you provide a rigorous proof?

The solution of OU process:
$$U_t = U_0e^{-\kappa t} + \sigma\int_0^te^{-\kappa (t-u)}dW_u$$
Hence, for all $a,b$ such that $0\le a<b$:
$$\begin{align}
\int_a^bU_sds&=U_0\cdot\frac{e^{-\kappa a}-e^{-\kappa b} }{\kappa} + \sigma\int_a^b \left(\int_0^se^{-\kappa (s-u)}dW_u  \right) ds \\
&=U_0\cdot\frac{e^{-\kappa a}-e^{-\kappa b} }{\kappa} + \int_0^b\left(\underbrace{\sigma\int_{\max\{a,u\}}^be^{-\kappa (s-u)}ds }_{:=f(u;a,b)}\right) dW_u\\
&=U_0\cdot\frac{e^{-\kappa a}-e^{-\kappa b} }{\kappa} + \int_0^b f(u;a,b) dW_u
\end{align}$$
Let's suppose $U_0$ follow the normal distribution and is independent to the Wiener process $W_t$ then $\int_a^bU_sds$ follows also a normal distribution of mean $\mathbb{E}(U_0)\cdot\frac{e^{-\kappa a}-e^{-\kappa b} }{\kappa}$ and variance $$\mathbb{V}\left(\int_a^bU_sds  \right) = \mathbb{V}(U_0)\cdot\left(\frac{e^{-\kappa a}-e^{-\kappa b} }{\kappa}\right)^2+\int_0^bf^2(u;a,b)du \tag{1}$$
A vector of Gaussian variables is a Gaussian vector if and only if any linear combination of its elements is Gaussian. Let us calculate the sum weighted by the coefficients $(a_1,...,a_n)$:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^na_i\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}U_sds &= U_0\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{e^{-\kappa t_{i-1}}-e^{-\kappa t_i} }{\kappa}}_{:=b_0} +\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\int_0^{t_i}f(u;t_{i-1},t_i)dWu\\
&= b_0U_0+\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i a_i\int_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j}f(u;t_{j-1},t_j)dWu\\
&=b_0U_0+ \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}_{:=b_j} \int_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j}f(u;t_{j-1},t_j)dWu \right)\\
&= b_0U_0+\sum_{j=1}^n b_j \int_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j}f(u;t_{j-1},t_j)dWu 
\end{align}$$
We know that $\left(\int_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j}f(u;t_{j-1},t_j)dWu \right)_{i=1,..,n}$ is a Gaussian vector and $U_0$ is independent to $W_t$ so the sum is a Gaussian variable.
We deduce then $\left(\int_{t_0}^{t_1}U_s\mathrm{d}s,~\int_{t_1}^{t_2}U_s\mathrm{d}s,~\ldots, ~\int_{t_{n-1}}^{t_n}U_s\mathrm{d}s\right)$ is a multivariate gaussian vector, the covariance between any two distinct integral variables can be calculated from this formula (with $a <b<c<d$)
$$\begin{align}
\text{Cov}\left(\int_a^bU_sds,\int_c^dU_sds \right)&= \mathbb{V}(U_0)\cdot\frac{(e^{-\kappa a}-e^{-\kappa b)})(e^{-\kappa c}-e^{-\kappa d)}) }{\kappa^2} +\text{Cov}\left(\int_0^bf(u;a,b)dW_u,\int_0^df(u;c,d)dW_u \right) \\
&=\mathbb{V}(U_0)\cdot\frac{(e^{-\kappa a}-e^{-\kappa b)})(e^{-\kappa c}-e^{-\kappa d)}) }{\kappa^2}  +\int_0^bf(u;a,b)f(u;c,d)du \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
That is
$$\left(\int_{t_0}^{t_1}U_s\mathrm{d}s,~\int_{t_1}^{t_2}U_s\mathrm{d}s,~\ldots, ~\int_{t_{n-1}}^{t_n}U_s\mathrm{d}s\right) \sim \mathcal{N}_n(\Gamma, \Sigma)$$
where

$\Gamma\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\Gamma_i = \mathbb{E}(U_0)\cdot\frac{e^{-\kappa t_i}-e^{-\kappa t_{i-1}} }{\kappa}$ for $i = 1,..,n$
$\Sigma\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $\Sigma_{ij}$ defined from the variance and covariance formulas $(1),(2)$ above.


Thanks. You deduce the marginal case that $\int_a^b U_s \mathrm{d}s$ is normal, but how to prove the joint distribution?

@jackwang I added a proof to prove the vector is a gaussian vector.
